# Как ускорить ввод двумерного массива?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь считать массив целых чисел. Естественно мне на вход попадают строки и... При решении задач, происходит ошибка по времени. Как я убедился это из-за считывания массива

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        for (int z = 0; z < N; z++)
            listarr[i, z] = s[z];
    }
```

Собственно, как в C# можно сделать считывание двумерного массива быстрее?